# Presence of autocorrelation and estimation of coefficients

Tags: regression, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, assumptions, quantile-regression

I am a beginner in quantile regression, quantreg package in R.I found that it is a good method to analyze data with outliers or non-normally disturbing data, but can´t find anything about homoscedasticity and autocorrelation assumptions. Research papers using quantile regression don´t mention it.

Can somebody help me with the assumptions that the model in quantile regression must fulfill? Are homoscedasticity and no autocorrelation important in this type of regression? I can not find any relevant literature about it. I know that heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation lead to the biased coefficient in the linear regression model and therefore I usually used variance-covariance matrix with appropriate arguments.

But how can I interpret the results of quantile regression, if there is a problem with autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, or both of them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["What are the assumptions for applying a quantile regression model?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320991/what-are-the-assumptions-for-applying-a-quantile-regression-model). See also ["What are the assumptions for quantile regression?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47929).

Comment: Though I have to say, a more comprehensive answer than the linked ones would be nice to have. These are nowhere near what we have for vanilla regression, unfortunately.